# Не меняется цвет фона кнопки

Tags: android, android-button, android-style

Пытаюсь поменять цвет фона кнопки на свой, добавив в качестве background своё png изображение `

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btContinue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_back2"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="ПРОДОЛЖИТЬ"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/tvTitle"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tvTitle"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvTitle">

    </com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton>
```

`

Но цвет кнопки всё равно остается фиолетовым, полупрозрачность фона добавляется, а цвет нет
[image: цвет кнопки]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    app:backgroundTint="@null"
    android:background="@drawable/button_gradient"
    ... />
```

Если вы используете пользовательский фон `android:background`, вам необходимо обязательно обнулить **backgroundTint** (либо `app:backgroundTint="@null"` или `app:backgroundTint="@empty"`), чтобы избежать окрашивания пользовательского фона.
при использовании кастомного `android:background`

Comment: Спасибо! Сработало